Generic Max() for Integer Types (including Boolean)
This is a follow-up to An Attempt at Creating Generic min()/max() for Fundamental Types.
What's Changed:

MIN() has been forsaken for the time being.
Mixed types now (should) work fine.
bool, char, signed char, unsigned char, short int, and unsigned short int, are implicitly promoted to int by adding 0, and are not checked for separately.
Floating point types have been dropped for two reasons:

OP does not care.
ISO C already gives too much attention to FP. C99 has fmin()/fmax(), and C23 has added fmaximum()/fminimum() and a lot of other variants. There was a proposal for other types after C23, and it might likely be accepted in C2Y, or whatever the next revision would be called.


No int overflow in the controlling expression of _Generic().

Code:
Expanding on chux's idea from the previous post, I ended up with:
#ifndef MAX_H
#define MAX_H 1

#include <limits.h>

#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION >= 202311L
    /* gnu::const is stricter than unsequenced, but it doesn't matter here. */
    #define ATTRIB_CONST            [[unsequenced]]
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
    #define ATTRIB_CONST            __attribute__((const))
#else
    #define ATTRIB_CONST            /**/
#endif

#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
    #define ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE    __attribute__((always_inline))
#else
    #define ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE    /**/
#endif

#define gen_basic_max(return_type, param_type1, param_type2, suffix)   \
    ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline return_type max_##suffix(param_type1 a, param_type2 b) \
    {   return a > b ? a : b;   }

gen_basic_max(int, int, int, i_i)
gen_basic_max(long, int, long, i_li)
gen_basic_max(long long, int, long long, i_lli)

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned int max_i_ui(int a, unsigned b)
{
    return a < 0 ? b : (b > (unsigned) a ? b : (unsigned) a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long max_i_uli(int a, unsigned long b)
{
    return a < 0 ? b : (b > (unsigned long) a ? b : (unsigned long) a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long max_i_ulli(int a, unsigned long long b)
{
    return a < 0 ? b : (b > (unsigned long long) a ? b : (unsigned long long) a);
}

#define MAX_I(a, b)     _Generic((b) + 0,                               \
                            int:                    max_i_i,            \
                            unsigned int:           max_i_ui,           \
                            long int:               max_i_li,           \
                            unsigned long int:      max_i_uli,          \
                            long long int:          max_i_lli,          \
                            unsigned long long int: max_i_ulli)((a), (b))

gen_basic_max(unsigned, unsigned, unsigned, ui_ui)
gen_basic_max(unsigned long, unsigned, unsigned long, ui_uli)
gen_basic_max(unsigned long long, unsigned, unsigned long long, ui_ulli)

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned max_ui_i(unsigned a, int b)
{
    return max_i_ui(b, a);
}

#if LONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long max_ui_li(unsigned a, long b)
#else
ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned max_ui_li(unsigned a, long b)
#endif
{
    if (a <= LONG_MAX) {
        return b < 0 ? a : ((long) a > b ? (long)a : b);
    }
    return b < 0 ? a : (a > (unsigned) b ? a : (unsigned) b);
}

#if LLONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long long max_ui_lli(unsigned a, long long b)
#else
ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned max_ui_lli(unsigned a, long long b)
#endif
{
    if (a <= LLONG_MAX) {
        return b < 0 ? a : ((long long) a > b ? (long long) a : b);
    }
    return b < 0 ? a : (a > (unsigned) b ? a : (unsigned) b);
}

#define MAX_UI(a, b)     _Generic((b) + 0,                              \
                            int:                    max_ui_i,           \
                            unsigned int:           max_ui_ui,          \
                            long int:               max_ui_li,          \
                            unsigned long int:      max_ui_uli,         \
                            long long int:          max_ui_lli,         \
                            unsigned long long int: max_ui_ulli)((a), (b))

gen_basic_max(long, long, int, li_i)
gen_basic_max(long, long, long, li_li)
gen_basic_max(long long, long, long long, li_lli)

#if LONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long max_li_ui(long a, unsigned b)
#else 
ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned max_li_ui(long a, unsigned b)
#endif
{
    return max_ui_li(b, a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long max_li_uli(long a, unsigned long b)
{
    return a < 0 ? b : (b > (unsigned long) a ? b : (unsigned long) a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long long max_li_ulli(long a, unsigned long long b)
{
    return a < 0 ? b : (b > (unsigned long long) a ? b : (unsigned long long) a);
}


#define MAX_LI(a, b)    _Generic((b) + 0,                               \
                            int:                    max_li_i,           \
                            unsigned int:           max_li_ui,          \
                            long int:               max_li_li,          \
                            unsigned long int:      max_li_uli,         \
                            long long int:          max_li_lli,         \
                            unsigned long long int: max_li_ulli)((a), (b))

gen_basic_max(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned, uli_ui)
gen_basic_max(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, uli_uli)
gen_basic_max(unsigned long long, unsigned long, unsigned long long, uli_ulli)

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long max_uli_i(unsigned long a, int b)
{
    return max_i_uli(b, a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long max_uli_li(unsigned long a, long b)
{
    return max_li_uli(b, a);
}

#if LLONG_MAX >= ULONG_MAX
ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long long max_uli_lli(unsigned long a, long long b)
#else 
ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long max_uli_lli(unsigned long a, long long b)
#endif
{
    if (a <= LLONG_MAX) {
        return b < 0 ? a : ((long long) a > b ? (long long) a : b);
    }
    return b < 0 ? a : (a > (unsigned long) b ? a : (unsigned long) b);
}

#define MAX_ULI(a, b)   _Generic((b) + 0,                               \
                            int:                    max_uli_i,          \
                            unsigned int:           max_uli_ui,         \
                            long int:               max_uli_li,         \
                            unsigned long int:      max_uli_uli,        \
                            long long int:          max_uli_lli,        \
                            unsigned long long int: max_uli_ulli)((a), (b))

gen_basic_max(long long, long long, int, lli_i)
gen_basic_max(long long, long long, long, lli_li)
gen_basic_max(long long, long long, long long, lli_lli)

#if LLONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long long max_lli_ui(long long a, unsigned b)
#else 
ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned max_lli_ui(long long a, unsigned b)
#endif
{
    return max_ui_lli(b, a);
}

#if LLONG_MAX >= ULONG_MAX
ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long long max_lli_uli(long long a, unsigned long b)
#else
ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long max_lli_uli(long long a, unsigned long b)
#endif
{
    return max_uli_lli(b, a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long long max_lli_ulli(long long a, unsigned long long b)
{
    return a < 0 ? b : (b > (unsigned long long) a ? b : (unsigned long long) a);
}

#define MAX_LLI(a, b)   _Generic((b) + 0,                               \
                            int:                    max_lli_i,          \
                            unsigned int:           max_lli_ui,         \
                            long int:               max_lli_li,         \
                            unsigned long int:      max_lli_uli,        \
                            long long int:          max_lli_lli,        \
                            unsigned long long int: max_lli_ulli)((a), (b))

gen_basic_max(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned, ulli_ui)
gen_basic_max(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long, ulli_uli)
gen_basic_max(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, ulli_ulli)

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long long max_ulli_i(unsigned long long a, int b)
{
    return max_i_ulli(b, a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long long max_ulli_li(unsigned long long a, long b)
{
    return max_li_ulli(b, a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long long max_ulli_lli(unsigned long long a, long long b)
{
    return max_lli_ulli(b, a);
}

#define MAX_ULLI(a, b)  _Generic((b) + 0,                               \
                            int:                    max_ulli_i,         \
                            unsigned int:           max_ulli_ui,        \
                            long int:               max_ulli_li,        \
                            unsigned long int:      max_ulli_uli,       \
                            long long int:          max_ulli_lli,       \
                            unsigned long long int: max_ulli_ulli)((a), (b))

#define MAX(a, b)       _Generic((a) + 0,                                   \
                            int:                    MAX_I((a) + 0, (b)),    \
                            unsigned int:           MAX_UI((a) + 0, (b)),   \
                            long int:               MAX_LI((a) + 0, (b)),   \
                            unsigned long int:      MAX_ULI((a) + 0, (b)),  \
                            long long int:          MAX_LLI((a) + 0, (b)),  \
                            unsigned long long int: MAX_ULLI((a) + 0, (b)))

#undef ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE
#undef ATTRIB_CONST
#undef C23_PLACEHOLDER

#endif  /* MAX_H */

To be used like this:
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <inttypes.h>

#include "max.h"

void test_max_int(void) 
{
    assert(MAX(3, 5) == 5);
    assert(MAX(-1, 1) == 1);
    assert(MAX(0, 0) == 0);
    assert(MAX(INT_MAX, INT_MIN) == INT_MAX);
    assert(MAX(-5, -3) == -3);
}

void test_max_unsigned_int(void) 
{
    assert(MAX(3U, 5U) == 5U);
    assert(MAX(0U, 0U) == 0U);
    assert(MAX(UINT_MAX, 0U) == UINT_MAX);
    assert(MAX(123456789U, 987654321U) == 987654321U);
}

void test_max_long(void) 
{
    assert(MAX(3L, 5L) == 5L);
    assert(MAX(-1L, 1L) == 1L);
    assert(MAX(0L, 0L) == 0L);
    assert(MAX(LONG_MAX, LONG_MIN) == LONG_MAX);
    assert(MAX(-5L, -3L) == -3L);
}

void test_max_unsigned_long(void) 
{
    assert(MAX(3UL, 5UL) == 5UL);
    assert(MAX(0UL, 0UL) == 0UL);
    assert(MAX(ULONG_MAX, 0UL) == ULONG_MAX);
    assert(MAX(123456789UL, 987654321UL) == 987654321UL);
}

void test_max_long_long(void) 
{
    assert(MAX(3LL, 5LL) == 5LL);
    assert(MAX(-1LL, 1LL) == 1LL);
    assert(MAX(0LL, 0LL) == 0LL);
    assert(MAX(LLONG_MAX, LLONG_MIN) == LLONG_MAX);
    assert(MAX(-5LL, -3LL) == -3LL);
}

void test_max_unsigned_long_long(void) 
{
    assert(MAX(3ULL, 5ULL) == 5ULL);
    assert(MAX(0ULL, 0ULL) == 0ULL);
    assert(MAX(ULLONG_MAX, 0ULL) == ULLONG_MAX);
    assert(MAX(123456789ULL, 987654321ULL) == 987654321ULL);
}

void test_max_mixed(void) 
{
    assert(MAX(3, 5U) == 5U);
    assert(MAX(-1, 1U) == 1U);
    assert(MAX(0L, 0) == 0L);
    assert(MAX(INT_MAX, LONG_MAX) == LONG_MAX);
    assert(MAX(LONG_MIN, LLONG_MIN) == LONG_MIN);
    assert(MAX(-5LL, 3UL) == 3UL);
    assert(MAX(3U, LLONG_MAX) == LLONG_MAX);
    assert(MAX(3LL, ULONG_MAX) == ULONG_MAX);
    assert(MAX(-1, 1ULL) == 1ULL);

    assert(MAX(-1, UINT_MAX) == UINT_MAX); 
    assert(MAX(-1L, ULONG_MAX) == ULONG_MAX); 
    assert(MAX(-1LL, ULLONG_MAX) == ULLONG_MAX); 
    assert(MAX(0, UINT_MAX) == UINT_MAX); 
    assert(MAX(0L, ULONG_MAX) == ULONG_MAX); 
    assert(MAX(0LL, ULLONG_MAX) == ULLONG_MAX); 

    assert(MAX(5, 5U) == 5U); 
    assert(MAX(5L, 5UL) == 5UL); 
    assert(MAX(5LL, 5ULL) == 5ULL); 

    assert(MAX(INT_MAX, UINT_MAX) == UINT_MAX); 
    assert(MAX(LONG_MAX, ULONG_MAX) == ULONG_MAX); 
    assert(MAX(LLONG_MAX, ULLONG_MAX) == ULLONG_MAX); 

    assert(MAX(INT_MIN, 0) == 0); 
    assert(MAX(INT_MIN, UINT_MAX) == UINT_MAX); 
    assert(MAX(LONG_MIN, ULONG_MAX) == ULONG_MAX); 
    assert(MAX(LLONG_MIN, ULLONG_MAX) == ULLONG_MAX); 
}

int main(void) 
{
    test_max_int();
    test_max_unsigned_int();
    test_max_long();
    test_max_unsigned_long();
    test_max_long_long();
    test_max_unsigned_long_long();
    test_max_mixed();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

All assertions pass, but there seem to be some unintended conversions that GCC is complaining about, which I find baffling. Moreover, Clang isn't reporting any such conversions, which is even more befuddling.
Review Request:
Bugs, wrong comparisons, redundant comparisons, portability. Any missing types?
How can I add some sort of debugging facility to this? For instance, I'd like to see which functions it selected for which types.

Follow-up:

Generic Min() for Integer Types (including Boolean)


MIN() next if this attempt is foolproof.

Too hairy for my little brain... But... You may be able to use all this work for MIN() if, somehow, you can simply wrap all of these max() thingies with min() versions that are only a ternary to return the OTHER value. If a is the MAX, then b must be the MIN... Maybe you're there already... G'night... :-)

@Fe2O3 Mhm, good idea. There are 36 total functions, 18 work on types with similar signs. I could use the max() ones for the types with dissimilar signs. GCC 14.1 with -O1 seem to generate the same code for min() and max() if I implement max() with min().

/* Current versions of gcc and clang support -std=c2x ...*/ -- note that the current release versions are GCC 14 and Clang 18; both support -std=c23.

@adabsurdum I should have written: "Current versions of gcc and clang installed on my system". I have Clang 18, but wasn't aware that it supported -std=c23. Thanks.

@Fe2O3 MIN() has now been implemented. Thanks for saving some of my time with the suggestion.

@adabsurdum Do you find it better to compare directly against == 202311L or > 201710L?

Exact comparison of versions is usually a mistake - you'll want your code to work on C++56, too.  I'd write >= 202311L.  (That's clearer than > 201710L because it points the reader at an actual minimum version the code is for, rather than some version it's not for).

@Harith -- I favor >= 202311L.

@adabsurdum I just found out that >= 202311L would evaluate to false with the std=c23 flag in GCC 14.1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78582932/20017547 Perhaps the original placeholder checker would be better, or > 201710L. I checked Clang 18.1's documentation and it defines it as 202311L.

@Harith -- Huh. That's weird; I guess GCC is waiting like the rest of us for the official C23 release party.... Maybe they think that the mandated value might change for the final release.

@adabsurdum — or maybe it's a simple oversight by the GCC team?  But that's why Harith is using > 201710L — if, indeed, the code is still using that.  Ideally, the test would be >= 202311L, but GCC 14.1 makes that awkward.  It's otherwise sufficiently C23 compatible, but doesn't use the official version number.

Tests
The assert() tests are not useful in release mode as that replaces assert() with empty code.
The test within the assert is wrought with type changes and so is not that great a test.
Better as
    unsigned u = UINT_MAX;
    long l = LONG_MAX;
    #if LONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
      long y = LONG_MAX;
    #else
      unsigned y = UINT_MAX;
    #endif
    if (y != MAX(u, l)) {
      printf("Failed unsigned, long\n");
    }

Although this tests the value it does not well test the return type of MAX().
Maybe something based on the below would help?:
#define typenameX(X) _Generic((X), \
_Bool: "_Bool", \
signed char: "signed char", \
char: "char", \
unsigned char: "unsigned char", \
short: "short", \
unsigned short: "unsigned short", \
int: "int", \
unsigned: "unsigned", \
long: "long", \
unsigned long: "unsigned long", \
long long: "long long", \
unsigned long long: "unsigned long long", \
float: "float", \
double: "double", \
long double: "long double", \
_Complex float: "_Complex float", \
_Complex double: "_Complex double", \
_Complex long double: "_Complex long double", \
void *: "void *", \
char *: "char *", \
const char *: "const char *", \
default: "UNKNOWN" \
)

unsigned u = UINT_MAX;
int i = INT_MAX;
unsigned y = UINT_MAX;
if (MAX(u,i) != y || strcmp(typenameX(MAX(u,i), "unsigned")) {
  printf("Error ...\n");
}

Mixed sign-ness and width
Candidate simplification:
(ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline was temporarily removed to better illustrate the idea.)
Rather than:
#if LONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
long max_ui_li(unsigned a, long b)
#else
unsigned max_ui_li(unsigned a, long b)
#endif
{
    if (a <= LONG_MAX) {
        return b < 0 ? a : ((long) a > b ? (long)a : b);
    }
    return b < 0 ? a : (a > (unsigned) b ? a : (unsigned) b);
}

Consider:
#if LONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
long max_ui_li(unsigned a, long b) {
  return (long) a > b ? (long) a : b;
}
#else
unsigned max_ui_li(unsigned a, long b) {
  return b < 0 ? a : (a > (unsigned) b ? a : (unsigned) b);
}
#endif


Just an hour ago I coded a generic typename and print with _Generic :-). Good to see I haven't made blunders.

"The test within the assert is wrought with type changes and so is not that great a test." ==> Does this apply to only mixed types here?

@Harith Even assert(MAX(3U, 5U) == 5U) performs a potential type change from the return of MAX(3U, 5U).  Say MAX(3U, 5U) errantly returned int, assert(MAX(3U, 5U) == 5U) would not detect that failing.

Wrong check for C23:
#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION >= 202311L

This check was expected to suffice for GCC 14.1 and Clang 18.1, as they both have added -std=c23 flags (Clang 18.1 documents the value of __STDC_VERSION__ to be 202311L), but empirically, GCC 14.1.0 still prints the placeholder version number 202000 when compiling with -std=c23 or -std=iso9899:2024 as shown in this StackOverflow answer by Jonathan Leffer: What is the STDC_VERSION value for C23?.
A better check would be (this is what OP had previously):
#define C23_PLACEHOLDER 202000L
#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= C23_PLACEHOLDER

Better set of tests:
Replacing the assertions with a custom test() macro, using typename() from chux's answer, the following tests both the return value and type of MAX():
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "max.h"

#define C23_PLACEHOLDER 202000L

#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= C23_PLACEHOLDER
    #define NORETURN    [[noreturn]]
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define NORETURN    __declspec(noreturn)
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
    #define NORETURN    __attribute__((noreturn))
#else
    #define NORETURN    _Noreturn
#endif

NORETURN static void cassert(const char cond[static 1], 
                             const char file[static 1],
                             size_t line)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "Assertion failed: '%s' at %s, line %zu.\n", cond, file, line);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

#define test(cond) do { \
    if (!(cond)) { cassert(#cond, __FILE__, __LINE__); } } while (false)

/* Get the name of a type */
#define ctypename(x) _Generic((x),                                  \
                _Bool: "_Bool",                                     \
                unsigned char: "unsigned char",                     \
                char: "char",                                       \
                signed char: "signed char",                         \
                short: "short",                                     \
                unsigned short: "unsigned short",                   \
                int: "int",                                         \
                unsigned: "unsigned",                               \
                long: "long",                                       \
                unsigned long: "unsigned long",                     \
                long long: "long long",                             \
                unsigned long long: "unsigned long long",           \
                default: "other")

static const int imax = INT_MAX;
static const unsigned umax = UINT_MAX;
static const long lmax = LONG_MAX;
static const unsigned long ulmax = ULONG_MAX;
static const long long llmax = LLONG_MAX;
static const unsigned long long ullmax = LLONG_MAX;

static const long lmin = LONG_MIN;
static const int imin = INT_MIN;
static const long long llmin = LLONG_MIN;

void test_max_int(void) 
{
    test(MAX(3, 5) == 5 && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(3, 5)), "int") == 0);
    test(MAX(-1, 1) == 1 && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-1, 1)), "int") == 0);
    test(MAX(0, 0) == 0 && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(0, 0)), "int") == 0);
    test(MAX(imax, imin) == imax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(imax, imin)), "int") == 0);
    test(MAX(-5, -3) == -3 && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-5, -3)), "int") == 0);
}

void test_max_unsigned_int(void) 
{
    test(MAX(3U, 5U) == 5U && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(3U, 5U)), "unsigned") == 0);
    test(MAX(0U, 0U) == 0U && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(0U, 0U)), "unsigned") == 0);
    test(MAX(umax, 0U) == UINT_MAX && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(umax, 0U)), "unsigned") == 0);
    test(MAX(65000U, 35000U) == 65000U && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(65000U, 35000U)), "unsigned") == 0);
}

void test_max_long(void) 
{
    test(MAX(3L, 5L) == 5L && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(3L, 5L)), "long") == 0);
    test(MAX(-1L, 1L) == 1L && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-1L, 1L)), "long") == 0);
    test(MAX(0L, 0L) == 0L && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(0L, 0L)), "long") == 0);
    test(MAX(lmax, lmin) == lmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(lmax, lmin)), "long") == 0);
    test(MAX(-5L, -3L) == -3L && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-5L, -3L)), "long") == 0);
}

void test_max_unsigned_long(void) 
{
    test(MAX(3UL, 5UL) == 5UL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(3UL, 5UL)), "unsigned long") == 0);
    test(MAX(0UL, 0UL) == 0UL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(0UL, 0UL)), "unsigned long") == 0);
    test(MAX(ulmax, 0UL) == ULONG_MAX && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(ulmax, 0UL)), "unsigned long") == 0);
    test(MAX(123456789UL, 987654321UL) == 987654321UL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(123456789UL, 987654321UL)), "unsigned long") == 0);
}

void test_max_long_long(void) 
{
    test(MAX(3LL, 5LL) == 5LL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(3LL, 5LL)), "long long") == 0);
    test(MAX(-1LL, 1LL) == 1LL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-1LL, 1LL)), "long long") == 0);
    test(MAX(0LL, 0LL) == 0LL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(0LL, 0LL)), "long long") == 0);
    test(MAX(llmax, llmin) == llmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(llmax, llmin)), "long long") == 0);
    test(MAX(-5LL, -3LL) == -3LL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-5LL, -3LL)), "long long") == 0);
}

void test_max_unsigned_long_long(void) 
{
    test(MAX(3ULL, 5ULL) == 5ULL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(3ULL, 5ULL)), "unsigned long long") == 0);
    test(MAX(0ULL, 0ULL) == 0ULL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(0ULL, 0ULL)), "unsigned long long") == 0);
    test(MAX(ullmax, 0ULL) == ullmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(ullmax, 0ULL)), "unsigned long long") == 0);
    test(MAX(123456789ULL, 987654321ULL) == 987654321ULL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(123456789ULL, 987654321ULL)), "unsigned long long") == 0);
}

void test_max_mixed(void) 
{
    test(MAX(3, 5U) == 5U && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(3, 5U)), "unsigned") == 0);
    test(MAX(-1, 1U) == 1U && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-1, 1U)), "unsigned") == 0);
    test(MAX(0L, 0) == 0L && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(0L, 0)), "long") == 0);

    test(MAX(imax, lmax) == lmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(imax, lmax)), "long") == 0);
    test(MAX(lmin, llmin) == lmin && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(lmin, llmin)), "long long") == 0);

    #if LLONG_MAX >= ULONG_MAX
    test(MAX(-5LL, 3UL) == 3UL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-5LL, 3UL)), "long long") == 0);
    test(MAX(3LL, ulmax) == ulmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(3LL, ulmax)), "long long") == 0);
    #else
    test(MAX(-5LL, 3UL) == 3UL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-5LL, 3UL)), "unsigned long") == 0);
    test(MAX(3LL, ulmax) == ulmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(3LL, ulmax)), "unsigned long") == 0);
    #endif

    #if LLONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
    test(MAX(3U, llmax) == llmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(3U, llmax)), "long long") == 0);
    #else
    test(MAX(3U, llmax) == llmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(3U, llmax)), "unsigned") == 0);
    #endif

    #if LONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
    test(MAX(umax, lmax) == lmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(umax, lmax)), "long") == 0);
    #else
    test(MAX(umax, lmax) == lmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(umax, lmax)), "unsigned") == 0);
    #endif

    #if ULLONG_MAX >= LONG_MAX
    printf("%s\n", ctypename(MAX(1000L, 500ULL)));
    test(MAX(1000L, 500ULL) == 1000L && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(1000, 500ULL)), "unsigned long long") == 0);
    test(MAX(-5000L, 30000ULL) == 30000ULL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-5000L, 30000ULL)), "unsigned long long") == 0);
    test(MAX(lmax, 0ULL) == lmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(lmax, 0ULL)), "unsigned long long") == 0);
    #else
    test(MAX(1000L, 500ULL) == 1000L && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(1000, 500ULL)), "long") == 0);
    test(MAX(-5000L, 30000ULL) == 30000ULL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-5000L, 30000ULL)), "long") == 0);
    test(MAX(lmax, 0ULL) == lmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(lmax, 0ULL)), "long") == 0);
    #endif

    test(MAX(-1, 1ULL) == 1ULL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-1, 1ULL)), "unsigned long long") == 0);

    test(MAX(-1, umax) == umax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-1, umax)), "unsigned") == 0); 
    test(MAX(-1L, ulmax) == ulmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-1L, ulmax)), "unsigned long") == 0); 
    test(MAX(-1LL, ullmax) == ullmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(-1LL, ullmax)), "unsigned long long") == 0); 
    test(MAX(0, umax) == umax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(0, umax)), "unsigned") == 0); 
    test(MAX(0L, ulmax) == ulmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(0, ulmax)), "unsigned long") == 0); 
    test(MAX(0LL, ullmax) == ullmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(0LL, ullmax)), "unsigned long long") == 0); 

    test(MAX(5L, 5UL) == 5UL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(5L, 5UL)), "unsigned long") == 0); 
    test(MAX(5LL, 5ULL) == 5ULL && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(5LL, 5ULL)), "unsigned long long") == 0); 

    test(MAX(imax, umax) == umax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(imax, umax)), "unsigned") == 0); 
    test(MAX(lmax, ulmax) == ulmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(lmax, ulmax)), "unsigned long") == 0); 
    test(MAX(llmax, ullmax) == ullmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(llmax, ullmax)), "unsigned long long") == 0); 

    test(MAX(imin, umax) == umax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(imin, umax)), "unsigned") == 0); 
    test(MAX(lmin, ulmax) == ulmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(lmin, ulmax)), "unsigned long") == 0);
    test(MAX(llmin, ullmax) == ullmax && strcmp(ctypename(MAX(llmin, ullmax)), "unsigned long long") == 0); 
}

int main(void) 
{
    test_max_int();
    test_max_unsigned_int();
    test_max_long();
    test_max_unsigned_long();
    test_max_long_long();
    test_max_unsigned_long_long();
    test_max_mixed();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


@chux Still error-prone?
